# Modifiers for HyperlinkEvent?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've got a wxPython application where I'm using an AuiNotebook, and HyperlinkCtrl widgets, to present the user with an interface sort of like tabbed web browsing.

Currently I open links in new tabs, or the current one, depending on the kind of link, etc. I'd like to let the users control whether or not they get a new window by having them control-click links. I can't find any way of doing that, though.

Thus: In my HyperlinkEvent handler, how can I determine if the user was using any keyboard modifiers while clicking?

Comment: Can't you use a variable to keep track of the keys pressed? So on key down assign the pressed key to it, and on key up set it to None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `wx.GetKeyState(int id)`:

(docs)

> Get the state of a key (true if pressed or toggled on, false if not.)
>   This is generally most useful getting the state of the modifier or
>   toggle keys.  On some platforms those may be the only keys that this
>   function is able to detect.

```
if wx.GetKeyState(wx.WXK_CONTROL):
    # open in new tab
else:
    # open in new windows
```